# Restricting SVN access for some users using "Path-based -authorization"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnserve

I am trying to use path-based -authorization. I have a working repository as follows:

```
   C:/SVNRepository/Test_Parent_folder/Test_child/test.txt
```

, that I need to restrict for user 'agupta'. My server URL is :

```
 http://ofsvn/repos/TEST_AG/TEST_AG_child/test.txt
```

In the authz file, I am trying to write :

```
  [/TEST_AG/TEST_AG_child/test.txt]
  agupta = r
```

I have also tried

```
  [repos:/TEST_AG/TEST_AG_child/test.txt]
  agupta = r
```

but it doesn't seem to be work as I can commit this file. I have already added 'authz-db = authz' to the svnserve.conf.

Can you please let me know what might be the reason that it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is your question starts with `http://` meaning that you use Apache server and the mod_dav_svn module to expose your repositories. However, you also say that you modify the `svnserve.conf` file. This file has nothing to do with the configuration of your current server! You need to configure Apache instead.

If you want to configure a server manually and use Apache HTTP Server. Read [SVNBook | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/).

You can also consider installing [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) - authentication and authorization as well as all other essential features all work out of the box and do not require manual setup.